# Why the height of the scroll view is longer than the actual content

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_bg" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo_area"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/share_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/photo_area"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/share_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/share_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/share_title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_textarea"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="default message" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/share_submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/share_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_taken_btn_submit" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the xml of the layout. The photo_area by default do not have image set but it will download a picture from internet and set on it. The problem is the height of the content view is longer than it should be, so there is a lot of empty space at the end . I try to removed the background in linearlayout, the height reduced a bit but still there are some empty space how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use android:adjustviewbound = "true" in the imageview xml fix the problem.